# Changing left position of relative div with Javascript not working in firefox/chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, html

I have this script running on my page that moves a div partially offscreen by changing its 'left' css attribute. It happens on page load if the page request contains a query string:

```
     function pageLoad() {

        var isQueryRequest = isQueryPostback(); // check for query string

        if(isQueryRequest)
        {
            document.getElementById("container").style.left = -340;  // not working

            document.getElementById("selectorText").innerHTML = "<< Show Query View";
            document.getElementById("querySelector").onclick = slideOut;
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("selectorText").innerHTML = "<< Hide Query View";
            document.getElementById("querySelector").onclick = slideIn;
        }
    }


    <div id="container" style="position:relative; left:30px;" >
       // contains other divs
    </div>
```

Ive confirmed that execution enters the first if block, but that line is not executing in Firefox or Chrome. It does execute fine in IE. There are no obvious errors on the page when looking at firebug.

Don't know if its relevant but this running in an .aspx page.

EDIT - slideIn() and slideOut() below:

```
  function slideOut() {

    var slidingDiv = document.getElementById("container");

    var stopPosition = 30;

    if (parseInt(slidingDiv.style.left) < stopPosition) {
        slidingDiv.style.left = parseInt(slidingDiv.style.left) + 28 + "px";
        setTimeout(slideOut, 1);
    }

    document.getElementById("selectorText").innerHTML = "<< Hide Query View";
    document.getElementById("querySelector").onclick = slideIn;  
  }

  function slideIn() {

    var slidingDiv = document.getElementById("container");
    var stopPosition = -340;

    if (parseInt(slidingDiv.style.left) > stopPosition) {
        slidingDiv.style.left = parseInt(slidingDiv.style.left) - 28 + "px";
        setTimeout(slideIn, 1);
    }

    document.getElementById("selectorText").innerHTML = "<< Show Query View";
    document.getElementById("querySelector").onclick = slideOut; 
  }
```

Comment: Can you post the `slideOut()` and `slideIn()` functions?

Comment: Just realized I might need to include 'px' ?

Comment: Does `style.left` output in `px`, or as an integer? I'd suggest using a JavaScript library for this sort of stuff (jQuery?), as you're kinda reinventing the wheel by manually animating. It's a good thing to do, but impractical in many cases.

Comment: I figured it out. IE accepts that you can set style.left using either a string literal, ie style.left = "30px" or you can just do style.left = 30. Firefox/chrome only seems to accept a string literal, so I changed style.left = -340 to style.left = "-340px" and it works.

Answer (score 0):

This might give you problems:

```
.innerHTML = "<< Show Query View";
```

Escape those less-than signs, as they might render as HTML, which'll screw up your layout:

```
.innerHTML = "&lt;&lt; Show Query View";
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the value in double quotes, like:

```
{
....
.......style.left="300px";
....
}
```